# FMDB query count

Tags: fmdb

I am creating an app that reads data from a db I created. The db has three tables: `CLIFFS`, `SECTORS`, `REGIONS`. I am using FMDB to extrapolate data from the `REGIONS` table but at the same time I have to do the count of the `CITY` in the table `FIELDS`.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

This is my code:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CLIMB.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if(!success){
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CLIMB.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    }
    if(!success){
        NSAssert1(0, @"failed to create writable db file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
    if(![db open])
    {
        NSLog(@"Err %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
    }

    [db setShouldCacheStatements:YES];

    NSString *sql = @"SELECT * FROM REGIONI;";


    FMResultSet  *rs = [db executeQuery:sql];

    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while( [rs next] )
    {
        CDEvent * region = [[CDEvent alloc] init];
        region.ID_SETTORE = [rs stringForColumn:@"ID_SETTORE"];
        region.REGIONE = [rs stringForColumn:@"REGIONE"];
        region.N_CITTA = [rs stringForColumn:@"N_CITTA"];
        region.CODICE_ID = [rs stringForColumn:@"CODICE_ID"];
        region.CITTA = [rs stringForColumn:@"CITTA"];


        [data addObject:region];

    }
    [rs close];
    [db close];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(CITY) FROM FIELDS];

NSInteger count = [db intForQuery: queryString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Before answer, I see something weird in the sql variable:

```
NSString *sql = @"SELECT * FROM REGIONI;";
```

Firstly, in SQLite is not necessary to use ¨;¨ in its statement. Secondly, you are consulting REGIONI when the Table (as you said) is REGIONS.

My answer:

```
FMResultSet *field = [db executeQuery:@"select count(CITY) from FIELDS as cities_number"];
int count = [field intForColumn:@"cities_number"];
NSLog(@"Number of cities: %i" , count);
```